# How to save the select history of a html form with multiple select drop down lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have created a wizzard with multiple forms. A user of the wizard can traverse through the forms back and forward using navigation buttons.
One of the forms contains multiple drop down lists, where the options in a list depends on the previous selection. Every option list is created using a webservice query. 
A user can always change a previous selection.

When all selections have been completed by the user, the form is submitted and the user enters the next form.
My question: how to save the select options history. We need this history including all the options in the drop down lists, if the user decides to go back to this form to modify his selections.

My own solution: saving the form (dom) instance ( in a cookie?). Is there a good alternative?

Answer (score 0):

You can load the options from that Web Service of yours while settings the cache property of the jQuery ajax method to true. This means further calls will be served from the browser cache. Please checkout this link for further info: http://jqapi.com/#p=jQuery.ajax

However, you can always cache those data using the localStorage, sessionStorage, globalStorage and the like on the client side. (Fore more info, please visit: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried using the cache. The default is : use the cache. But in my network panel the ajax json post queries where send and not cached? The article was very helpfull.To use local storage in browsers like IE7 you have to emulate it, using cookie storage.