# How to serialize a jquery object like a drop down list in a cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have some form data with drop down lists. I want to save the drop down lists including all the options in a cookie.
JSON stringify returns an error : Converting circular structure to JSON.
Ofcourse I can iterate through all the select options and create a CSV like string in the cookie.

Comment: are you using this library https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serialize a DOM object, the format of choice will be XML. If you want to serialize an Array of option values, you will need to extract them - you can't JSON-encode a jQuery object.

Comment: which serializer to use for xml.

Comment: A [XMLSerializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLSerializer) would be the counterpart to a DOMParser, yet I think in your case inner/outerHTML will be enough.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I already tried using .html() to put all the selects in one cookie. But the html exceeds the cookie size. Maybe I have to use a cookie for every select. I will also try the XMLserializer.

Comment: No, if it's so much data cookies are the wrong approach anyway. Tell us why you want to store them, whether you want to store them client- or serverside and we may lead you to a better solution. Please put that information in your original question.

Comment: This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582550/how-to-save-the-select-history-of-a-html-form-with-multiple-select-drop-down-list shows you my problem.